# How to Insert multiple data rows in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie to .NET and want help with multiple rows insert action into the same table.

I am able to submit the form with multiple rows without a FOREIGNKEY, however when use FOREGIN KEY which is the User Name and ID for User it throws as error.

This is my updated code:

Model class:

```
public class DailyTask
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller `POST` action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddDsr(List<DailyTask> ci)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(ci);
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (Db dc = new Db())
                {
                    var uname = User.Identity.Name;

                    User userdto = dc.Users.Where(x => x.Email == uname).FirstOrDefault();

                    

                    foreach (var i in ci)
                    {
                        dc.DailyTasks.Add(i);
                                               
                    }

                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    TempData["Message"] = "DSR successfully send!";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ci = new List<DailyTask> { new DailyTask { Id = 0, Project = "", Task = "", Status = "" } };
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("AddDsr")
}
```

View

```
@model List<Lixto.Models.VM.DailyTask>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BulkData";
}

<h2>BulkData</h2>
<style>
    td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddDsr", "SendDSR", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        if (TempData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px green" class="alert alert-success">
                @TempData["Message"]
            </div>
        }

        <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add New</a></div>
        <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {


                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Project)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Task)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Status)</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (j > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
    }


</div>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Project)</div>
        
}
    

    @* Here I will add Jquery Code for validation / dynamically add new rows / Remove rows etc *@

    @section Scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                //1. Add new row
                $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
                    var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
                    var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

                    var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                    $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
                    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                        // Replaced Name
                        var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                        var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                        $(this).attr('name', newN);
                        //Replaced value
                        var type = $(this).attr('type');
                        if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                            $(this).attr('value', '');
                        }

                        // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                        $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

                    });
                    $trLast.after($trNew);

                    // Re-assign Validation
                    var form = $("form")
                        .removeData("validator")
                        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                });

                // 2. Remove
                $('a.remove').live("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });

            });
        </script>
    }
```

This is what I have tried with no success:

1. View has a form which has 3 fields
2. I have added a button which can add same field set multiple times in order to add more rows
3. Wrote an action method which inserts the data into the table for only 1 row

What am I expecting?

User should be able to click Add button and add more than 1 tasks and all entries should get inserted into the table.

Currently it only submits 1 row.

Comment: I have managed to somehow submit the data as I want to it be, however there is bit of challenge. I have also included User name in the Model Class as a Foreign Key. With this new change my code fails on submitting the data into the table. See the above updated code.